# How to Save Recorded video to camera roll?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, video-capture, avcapturesession, alassetslibrary

I am trying to record video with iPhone camera and saving to camera roll following this [blog](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2). However, using `AVCaptureSession` ,camera gets initialized. But when try to save video to camera roll, it gives `URL` error. Here's my code snippet

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"myApp.mov"];

            NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:outputPath];
          //  NSLog(@"Output URL  %@ AND ABSOLUTE STRING %@",outputURL,outputURL.absoluteString);
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
            {
                NSError *error;
                if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO)
                {
                    //Error - handle if requried
                }
            }
            //Start recording
            [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

It gives the below error

> [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
>   startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - Cannot record to
>   URL
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FEA51E75-B2A6-45DD-991B-AFFBF5794EAC/tmp/myApp.mov
>   because it is not a file URL.

But if I change `URL` to `initFileURLWithPath`, it gives another error.

> Video
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6876493-4354-4607-B348-63C5262AF2D9/tmp/myApp.mov
>   cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on
>   this server."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6876493-4354-4607-B348-63C5262AF2D9/tmp/myApp.mov,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6876493-4354-4607-B348-63C5262AF2D9/tmp/myApp.mov,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server., NSUnderlyingError=0x171ad710 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"},
>   NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6876493-4354-4607-B348-63C5262AF2D9/tmp/myApp.mov}

I really don't understand the error. Can anyone please help me sorting this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried like this:

```
   NSString *outputFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"myApp" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]];
```

Ref : same example like you are working, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118720/4557505

else

```
NSString *rootPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString  *videoPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.mov"];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

The above code works for me in `copyItemAtURL`

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it didn't work. Gave me same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Developer Apple site has a good example how to work with video from iPhone camera, preprocess and save video to camera roll. 
Visit link [RosyWriter example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) and click "download sample" button on top of the article.

This tutorial also shows how to use OpenCV and OpenGL libraries to preprocess video.